# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null error

Tags: laravel

the dropzone not sending filename on controller

```
<form  method="post" action="{{ route('student.profile.update',$student->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class=dropzone id="dropzone" files = true >


 Dropzone.options.dropzone =
            {
                maxFilesize: 12,
                renameFile: function (file) {
                    var dt = new Date();
                    var time = dt.getTime();
                    return time + file.name;
                },
                acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function (file, response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (file, response) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Show your controller.

Comment: public function profileUpdate(Request $request,$id){


    $std= Student::find($id);

    $std->first_name=$request->first_name;
    $std->last_name=$request->last_name;
    $std->email=$request->email;
    $std=>password=bcrypt($request->password);


    $image = $request->file('file');

    $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->move(public_path('images'),$imageName);

    $std->imag= $imageName;
    $std->save();

Comment: $image is null;

Comment: Please post your view code here and try ```dd($request->all())``` at the top of controller.

Comment: only token generated dd($request->all()) i try

Comment: if am use <input type="file"> its works but dropzone not working

Comment: You have to give ```name``` to your input fields or else it won`t work.

Comment: ```<input type="file" name="file">``` Like this.

Comment: yes manual imageuploadding is working

Comment: but dropzone not sending file name

Comment: <form  method="post" action="{{ route('student.profile.update',$student->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class=dropzone id="dropzone" files = true >